# inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python

не могу понять где косяк помогите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста выложитe код текстом.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CEpXbsaxp6xFFJwLqaGdJGyzflCxsIibyEOUDbCWSfc/edit?usp=sharing

Вот код

Comment: `sed -i -e 's,\t,\ \ \ \ ,g' source_file_name.py` вам покажет потом, что не так. (Из-за синтаксиса комментариев пришлось перед каждым пробелом поставить `\\`, что в принципе не нужно)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка дословно переводится так: некорректное использование пробелов и табов. У строки где ошибка отступы сделайте пробелами.

Comment: Да я понимаю но я уже все перепробовал помогите пожалуйста решить

Comment: @Mark_Pro_100, см. мой комментарий выше.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит о том, что у вас для отступов где-то используются табы, где-то пробелы. Так лучше не делать, и настроить редактор кода, чтобы отступы всегда выполнялись пробелами. Можно использовать и табы, но не смесь табов и пробелов, но [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) рекомендует всегда использовать пробелы для отступов (4 пробела на уровень отступа). (Технически можно использовать отступы табами и пробелы в одном файле, но для одного и того же уровня отступа должен использоваться один и тот же способ. Но опять же лучше так не делать, чтобы не усложнять себе жизнь.)

В Sublime Text в меню `View -> Indentation` (отступы) нужно поставить галку напротив `Indent Using Spaces` (делать отступы пробелами). Дальше во всех ваших Python файлах нужно выполнить пункт `Convert Indentation to Spaces` (конвертировать отступы в пробелы) из этого же меню.

Answer (score 0):

выберите команду Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings и найдите файл Preferences.sublime-settings-User. Включите в этот файл следующий фрагмент:

```
{

    "rulers": [80],
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

после того настройки линейки и табуляций будут действовать во всех файлах. Следите за тем чтобы каждая строка кроме последней завершалась запятой.

Answer (score -1):

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class CalculatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        gl = GridLayout(cols=4)

        gl.add_widget(Button(text="7"))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="8"))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="9"))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="X"))

        gl.add_widget(Button(text="7"))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="8"))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="9"))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="-"))

        gl.add_widget(Button(text="1"))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="2"))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="3"))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="+"))

        gl.add_widget(Widget())
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="0"))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="."))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text="="))

        return gl


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CalculatorApp().run()
```